# How to limit a process to one CPU core in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, cpu, limit

How to limit process to one cpu core ?

Something similar to `ulimit` or `cpulimit` would be nice. (Just to ensure: I do NOT want to limit percentage usage or time of execution. I want to force app (with all it's children, processes (threads)) to use one cpu core (or 'n' cpu cores)).

Comment: I've pointed out earlier that : Searching taskset on unix.SO gave me those two related questions : [1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-can-i-set-the-processor-affinity-of-a-process-on-linux), [2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/using-linux-cgroups-to-balance-cpu-performance) , where `taskset` is used. - It's similar question, that's why I linked this with them, but asked in different way, so I could not find it, when searching for my problem. Those questions where linked together when @DavidSchwartz shown `taskset` in his comment.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247209/135943

Comment: Very good question!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Under Linux, execute the [`sched_setaffinity`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) system call. The affinity of a process is the set of processors on which it can run. There's a standard shell wrapper: [`taskset`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html). For example, to pin a process to CPU #0 (you need to choose a specific CPU):

```
taskset -c 0 mycommand --option  # start a command with the given affinity
taskset -c -pa 0 1234            # set the affinity of a running process
```

---

There are third-party modules for both Perl ([`Sys::CpuAffinity`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys::CpuAffinity)) and Python ([`affinity`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/affinity)) to set a process's affinity. Both of these work on both Linux and Windows (Windows may require other third-party modules with `Sys::CpuAffinity`); `Sys::CpuAffinity` also works on several other unix variants.

If you want to set a process's affinity from the time of its birth, set the current process's affinity immediately before calling `execve`. Here's a trivial wrapper that forces a process to execute on CPU 0.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use POSIX;
use Sys::CPUAffinity;
Sys::CpuAffinity::setAffinity(getpid(), [0]);
exec $ARGV[0] @ARGV
```

Comment: For a working solution for Python 3, see this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31370840/5079779

Comment: The problem is that the process can just call `sched_setaffinity` to undo the taskset and run on other CPUs: i.e., it isn't like a ulimit where the process is forced to stay within the limits. It's more like a suggestion.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Right, it isn't a security restriction. If you want a security restriction, you need different tools. I think you can do it with cgroups.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm investigating: https://forum.peppermintos.com/index.php?topic=8777.new#new

Comment: When changing the CPU affinity of a running process, `taskset -c -p 0 1234` will not work. We need to pass parameter `-a` as follows: `taskset -c -p -a 0 1234`. Check out the comments for this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146833/267627)

Comment: @NagabhushanSN It does work if the process is single-threaded. But for a multithreaded process you do need `-a` to affect all the threads, so it's a good idea to include it in my answer. I've done that, thanks.

Comment: Good answer works for me!

Comment: Awesome! Adding the flag `-a` helped me set a multi-processor process to a limited set of CPU cores. FYI, I was trying to run it on the first four cores. so, I used `-a 0-3` to specify that

Answer (score 7):

You can build cpu-sets on the command line as well. `man cpuset`
Later on you can assign (running) processes to these.

Comment: I've checked out man page. Looks very interesting ! Thanks for this ! What about my question, I'd like to get processes assigned from their birth. Even thou, it's interesting to know how to assign running ones. :)

Comment: It has been a long time that I actually needed that - it was on Solaris. Later on it was on HP-Unix. On Linux - hm. I think I once found an additional package in SLES that provides a shell-api for that stuff. A quick search on CentOS 5 turned out blank. I will come back to you, if I found something in that direction. BTW - wich Linux distribution are we talking about here?

Comment: I am looking for general solution. If some program is not delivered in standard distro, I can deliver it. What about my desktop: Arch64, Arch. On servers usually Gentoo. On ARM devices, usually small specific ones.

Comment: My feeling is that you can do all the cpuset-magic with echo in /proc as well. But you are propably better off in your case with the python solution. - I see the command on the shell is `taskset`.

Comment: `/proc` is good tip, I have to check it out. Thanks.