# Is there a way to change the number of processors a program sees?

Tags: shell, process, cpu, resources, multiprocessor

Is there any way I can trick a program into thinking the system has fewer processors? To explain: I am debugging a program that creates as many threads as it has processors, using `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF);`. I'd like to test it using only one threat. Strictly for convenience, I'd like to know if there's a way I can trick the program into thinking the computer only has one processor, to avoid having to add a command line option or changing the code to temporarily only create one thread.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23106/limit-process-to-one-cpu-core

Comment: You can override any library/system call with `LD_PRELOAD` or `ptrace`. I don't know if there's a ready-made solution.

Comment: You could run it under a virtual machine that only has one virtual processor.

Answer (score 1):

Under **FreeBSD** (>=7.1), you can use the /usr/bin/cpuset command eg :

```
# cpuset -l 0,2 -c -p <pid>
```

Under **Linux**, see : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html